# Javascript - check if string is in json and identify the parent

Tags: javascript, json

I would like to create something to check if a value is in my json data and then retrieve group in which he belongs.

```
data = [{
  "1" : ["1007","1020"],
  "2" : ["1200","1493"],
  "3" : ["6754","8652"],
}]

var value = '1200' #how to identify if 1200 is in group 2.
```

I have no clue on how I can do that. Any help would be useful!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
data = [{
  "1" : ["1007","1020"],
  "2" : ["1200","1493"],
  "3" : ["6754","8652"],
}]

for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    for (var key in data[i])
    {
        if (data[i][key].indexOf('1200') !== -1){
            console.log(key);
        }
    }
}
```

basically, you are looping through the array of objects and then looping through the keys of each object to test if your element belongs to the value of each key.

Answer (score 0):

First you get all keys of your object and then you filter by `1200`. At the end you convert it to a string.

```
for(var i = 0;i < data.length;++i) {
    var group = Object.keys(data[i]).filter(function(key) {
        return data[i][key].indexOf("1200") !== -1;
    }).toString();
}
```

In ES6/7 you can do it a bit smoother:

```
Object.keys(data[i]).filter(key => data[i][key].includes("1200")).toString();
```